# Ionic - 500 Internal Server Error if the Service Runs in Real Device. Runs Perfectly on browser

Tags: http, ionic-framework, header

I am Integrating my wordpress site with an Android app using woo-commerce Plugin.
I am trying to update an item's quantity using an API.

When I run the app in the browser, the API runs fine. when i run the same API in the real device,it gives me 500 internal server error.

In fact, running in postman is also successful.

Here is my code for what i am trying to achieve:

```
let body = {
      cart_item_key: this.getKey,
      quantity: this.updatedQty 
  }




this.http.post(url,body).subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data.json());

     this.toast.show(data.json(), '3000', 'bottom').subscribe(
        toast => {
           console.log(toast);
        }
      );
     },error => {
       console.log(error);
       load.dismiss();
       this.toast.show(error, '3000', 'bottom').subscribe(
        toast => {
           console.log(toast);
        }
      );
  });
```

I am Attaching the Response as well as the headers i am getting from the server

[image: response in postman]

[image: The Related Headers]

this is what i get in the real Android Device while running the same API

[image: API returns error]

Please Anyone can tell me What is the actual Problem?

Thank you in Advance..

Comment: And, using a debugging proxy like Fiddler on your PC, and your phone's HTTP proxy set to use it, exactly what data is your phone sending, in order to cause this error? You can also use Wireshark and pick up the HTTP packets off your local network. Do make sure it's HTTP though; trying to debug HTTPS in this fashion is a challenge. Couldn't help but notice it's not exactly a fair test given that you updated the quantity of a CPU in the working one and a rug in the broken one.. Maybe it's broken for everything, but good testing in a working/nonworking scenario is to equalize as much as possible

Comment: ps; screenshots are less useful than the actual text data. Put the raw http request and response from both devices into code blocks in your question. You'll probably realise the problem soon after you do, maybe something like in the browser it sends the qty as 9, and in the app sends it as "9"

Comment: CPU and the Rug have different keys associated with them .! am just posting the key and the updated quantity into the body. now, in my device, i am updating my quantity in realtime i.e as the user enters the quantity, a second later the API runs and updates the qty

Comment: ok let me do the same in your in your 2nd comment

Comment: I got the Problem. The Response time for device and the browser is different. the device's response time is bit faster than the browser. the key in the body is received asynchronously.since the browser is slower,it receives the key first but this is not a case in the device. when the API runs key is undefined and hence 500 internal server error. your second comment led me to find out this issue when i checked the body i created and found the key is undefined..thanks again